# Excel VBA MYSQL Query execution was interrupted, maximum statement execution time exceeded

Tags: mysql, vba, execution-time

I am trying to operate a SQL query using excel VBA

> select count(distinct column_name) from db_name.table_name

but, I end up with the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'
>       [MySQL] [ODBC 8.00(w) Driver][mysqld-5. 7.21] Query execution was 
>       interrupted, maximum statement execution time exceeded

There are 4 million records in the table with 230 columns. I have tried increasing "max_execution_time" value but it does not help. The error comes up in 30 seconds after execution.

How can I get past this timeout issue?

- MYSQL version 5.7.21 (WAMP 32 bit)
- Excel - Office 365

Comment: Using a passthrough query?

Comment: I don't have MS Access installed, I guess that's what you meant to use right?!

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905858/cannot-use-pass-through-queries-in-excel) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905858/cannot-use-pass-through-queries-in-excel

Comment: Have come across it for the first time, let me post back what I get - in some time.

Comment: Have you tried this query with a shell (command line) `mysql` client?

Comment: What did you set `max_execution_time` to? And did you restart the MySQL server after changing the global variable? Please show the actual VBA code block including connection and recordset call (not line snippet of SQL). You can set query time on the ODBC call.

Comment: Yes, I tried the query on MYSQL shell cmd, it ran successfully "1 row in set (32.66 sec)" . Also, I had restarted the mysql server after setting global max_execution_time as 6000. In VBA its not completing the execution still.

Comment: How can I do this "You can set query time on the ODBC call"? All I am trying to do is run a query for a table to first fetch the fields and then get the count of distinct values in each field. I couldn't write successfully a dynamic query procedure (am not an sql person) in mysql workbench so tried my hand at VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been struggling for while with a similar problem. I see your post is an old post, but who knows, maybe it can still help you or anyone that comes for a solution to this problem.
What I did was divide the SELECT process in batches.
So I have a column called Unique (which is the primary key and auto-increasing).
So in VBA i do a FOR/NEXT loop, kinda like this:

```
For i= 0 to 10,000,000
Select * from table where unique>= i and unique< i+1,000,000
```

Then I copy the query to another cell, compiling all the queries
next.

Well, it's not the perfect solution, but it worked for me and hope it helps someone!